# Establish connection to a database in knime

Tags: knime

I am performing a data quality task on knime. After performing it I am trying write the cleaned data into a table in mysql database.

I am facing the error as **Execute failed: Could not create connection to database server.**
Below is attached link of settings configuration of database writer.

[Refer this image to look at configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0YjA.png)

Knime version : 3.7.2

I would request anyone please help me understand where I went wrong and help me solve this :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configure as follow:

1. Use "MySQL Connector" node to establish the connection to the Database
2. Use "DB Writer" node to write the table/data, this node will allow you to drop and rewrite or append data

[Here](https://screenshot.googleplex.com/pnRBNwx3w4QKHLM.png) the screenshot of my actual setup with incoming data, connection and write.